# R: Calculating linear models with long vector of predictor variables resulting in parse error

Tags: r, formula, paste, lm

I am trying to calculate a couple of linear models with a long list of predictor variables. Therefore I first define my predictor variables in a long string:

```
#### define predictors ####
all_predictors <- "age + gender + study + ACHIEVER + PLAYER + SOCIALIZER + DISRUPTOR + FREE_SPIRIT + PHILANTHROPIST + INF_POP + PLE_STIM + P19_SDI_thought + P19_SDI_action + P19_Stimulat + P19_Hedonism + P19_Achievement + P19_Power.resources + P19_Power.dominance + P19_Face + P19_Sec.personal + P19_Sec.societal + P19_Traditio + P19_conf_rules + P19_conf_interpersonal + P19_Humility + P19_bene_dependability + P19_bene_caring + P19_univ.concern + P19_univ.nature + P19_univ.tolerance + OFA_Expl + OFA_Geni + OFA_Genw + OFA_Deta + OFA_List + OFA_Comm + OFA_IdeB + OFA_IdeC + OFA_Find + OFA_Coll + OFA_Buil + OFA_Subm + OFA_MakA + OFA_MakF + OFA_ForI + OFA_Give + OFA_Rate + OFA_ForQ + OFA_GenT + OFA_Ment + OFA_Spi, comb"
```

Then I try to combine the predictors with my dependent variable and call the lm model:

```
#### OFM_Subm  ####
OLS_OFM_Subm <- lm(paste("OFM_Subm ~ ", all_predictors, sep = ""))
```

However I always get the following error:

```
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:1:708: unexpected ','
1: ture + P19_univ.tolerance + OFA_Expl + OFA_Geni + OFA_Genw + OFA_Deta + OFA_List + OFA_Comm + OFA_IdeB + OFA_IdeC + OFA_Find + OFA_Coll + OFA_Buil + OFA_Subm + OFA_MakA + OFA_MakF + OFA_ForI +
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried tinkering around with `as.formula` and `formula` however no sucess so far.

The formula I put together with p`aste("OFM_Subm ~ ", all_predictors, sep = "")` looks fine:

```
"OFM_Subm ~ age + gender + study + ACHIEVER + PLAYER + SOCIALIZER + DISRUPTOR + FREE_SPIRIT + PHILANTHROPIST + INF_POP + PLE_STIM + P19_SDI_thought + P19_SDI_action + P19_Stimulat + P19_Hedonism + P19_Achievement + P19_Power.resources + P19_Power.dominance + P19_Face + P19_Sec.personal + P19_Sec.societal + P19_Traditio + P19_conf_rules + P19_conf_interpersonal + P19_Humility + P19_bene_dependability + P19_bene_caring + P19_univ.concern + P19_univ.nature + P19_univ.tolerance + OFA_Expl + OFA_Geni + OFA_Genw + OFA_Deta + OFA_List + OFA_Comm + OFA_IdeB + OFA_IdeC + OFA_Find + OFA_Coll + OFA_Buil + OFA_Subm + OFA_MakA + OFA_MakF + OFA_ForI + OFA_Give + OFA_Rate + OFA_ForQ + OFA_GenT + OFA_Ment + OFA_Spi, comb"
```

For clarification the lm call I want to make is:

```
lm(OFM_Subm ~ age + gender + study + ACHIEVER + PLAYER + SOCIALIZER + DISRUPTOR + FREE_SPIRIT + PHILANTHROPIST + INF_POP + PLE_STIM + P19_SDI_thought + P19_SDI_action + P19_Stimulat + P19_Hedonism + P19_Achievement + P19_Power.resources + P19_Power.dominance + P19_Face + P19_Sec.personal + P19_Sec.societal + P19_Traditio + P19_conf_rules + P19_conf_interpersonal + P19_Humility + P19_bene_dependability + P19_bene_caring + P19_univ.concern + P19_univ.nature + P19_univ.tolerance + OFA_Expl + OFA_Geni + OFA_Genw + OFA_Deta + OFA_List + OFA_Comm + OFA_IdeB + OFA_IdeC + OFA_Find + OFA_Coll + OFA_Buil + OFA_Subm + OFA_MakA + OFA_MakF + OFA_ForI + OFA_Give + OFA_Rate + OFA_ForQ + OFA_GenT + OFA_Ment + OFA_Spi, comb)
```

As I have to run many models with these same predictor variables I want to shorten the code for better readability.

Comment: A valid formula cannot contain `,`.

Comment: Hmm but the correct formula for lm is lm(DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + ..., data)?

Here my data is stored in the "comb" data frame.

Comment: lol. The _formula_ you're after is `OFM_Subm ~ age + gender + ... + OFA_Spi`. The _data_ is `comb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm it seems that there are no commas allowed in the formula (thanks to the commenters!). So I got what I wanted by taking the dataframe out of the predictors variable and calling:

```
OLS_OFM_Subm <- lm(paste("OFM_Subm ~ ", all_predictors, sep = ""), comb)
```